# Error message that I can't solve

Tags: android

I'm getting this error message: requestFeature() must be called before adding content. I have read other questions about this error message here at stackowerflow, and if I understand it correct, it's all about don't call setContentView() before requestFeature(). But isn't this what I have done in my onCreate method? Or could the error have to do with something else? I'm confused and would preciate some help to solve this error! Thanks!

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Set screen to landscape
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    // Remove title from screen
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    // Set screen to full screen
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    // Create a new object of GameLoop and pass this context
    gameLoop = new GameLoop(this);
    gameLoop.setOnTouchListener(this);
    setContentView(gameLoop);
}
```

EDIT: The LogCat

```
04-25 08:19:07.937: I/ApplicationPackageManager(6365): cscCountry is not German : NEE
04-25 08:19:08.085: W/dalvikvm(6365): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
04-25 08:19:08.101: E/AndroidRuntime(6365): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10
04-25 08:19:08.101: E/AndroidRuntime(6365): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-25 08:19:08.101: E/AndroidRuntime(6365):     at  com.android.mergemania.GameLoop.drawObjects(GameLoop.java:78)
04-25 08:19:08.101: E/AndroidRuntime(6365):     at  com.android.mergemania.GameLoop.run(GameLoop.java:63)
04-25 08:19:08.101: E/AndroidRuntime(6365):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Comment: Do you have any decorations in the manifest Activity declaration?

Comment: No, I havn't done anything with the manifest file! What else could be wrong?

Comment: what is happening in the `GameLoop` class at line 78?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must set the orientation after requesting window feature. your statements must be in the below order

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Remove title from screen
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    // Set screen to full screen
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    // Set screen to landscape
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    // Create a new object of GameLoop and pass this context
    gameLoop = new GameLoop(this);
    gameLoop.setOnTouchListener(this);
    setContentView(gameLoop);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't helping anything :( I have done an application with this order that I have in my code before and that worked fine. So what could the the problem be? I can't continue with my works, it's so irritating

Comment: could you please update your question with complete logcat stacktrace?

Comment: Sorry, but now it seems like there is some other problem! Perhaps my first problem is solved, but my app still close!

Comment: you have `nullpointerexception` at line 78 in GameLoop.java. Check for any objects for null vales. If u can't solve it, open a new question because your original question has been salved

Answer (score 1):

try for this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Set screen to landscape
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    // Remove title from screen

    // Set screen to full screen
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    // Create a new object of GameLoop and pass this context
    gameLoop = new GameLoop(this);
    gameLoop.setOnTouchListener(this);
    setContentView(gameLoop);
}
```

Comment: No it isn't. Perhaps is some other problems